# Get stream data from Qt QMediaPlayer

Tags: qt, gstreamer, qmediaplayer

I use `QMediaPlayer` to play online mp3 and I want to download the whole mp3 data when buffer is complete. But the only function relate to it is `setMedia(const QMediaContent & media, QIODevice * stream = 0)`.

And the stream pointer is used to put in the data . So I try to use `QReply` as its arg.And it fails absolutely.

```
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl((QUrl(source)));
pReply = mgr.get(request);
setMedia(QUrl(),pReply);
```

The `mgr` is QNetworkAccessManager and source is the online url of mp3.

My question is : is there any way to get the music data? Is `setMedia` can do it ?

--------------------------Update----------------

I connect the reply's `readReady` signal and put it into `setMedia` at first time that reply have something to read.But the `QMediaPlayer` return the `QMediaPlayer::ResourceError` error.

P.S. I added the `QMediaPlayer::StreamPlayback` flag.

------------------------update--------------------------------------

I found why my code don't work.
The `setMedia` function call `DirectShowPlayerService::load` inertal.
And there is a line check like this:

```
else if (stream && (!stream->isReadable() || stream->isSequential())) {
    m_pendingTasks = 0;
    m_graphStatus = InvalidMedia;
    m_error = QMediaPlayer::ResourceError;
}
```

For `isSequential()` there is doc:

> bool QIODevice::isSequential() const [virtual]
>   Returns true if this device is sequential; otherwise returns false.
>
> Sequential devices, as opposed to a random-access devices, have no concept of a start, an end, a size, or a current position, and they do not support seeking. You can only read from the device when it reports that data is available. **The most common example of a sequential device is a network socket**. On Unix, special files such as /dev/zero and fifo pipes are sequential.
>
> Regular files, on the other hand, do support random access. They have both a size and a current position, and they also support seeking backwards and forwards in the data stream. Regular files are non-sequential.

At last , the network reply can't be used in this condition. :-（

So My further research may be : how dose Qt deal with the network socket for this . And is there any way to get the data ?

------------------update----------------------

It seems that `QMediaPlayer` is based on `GStreamer` and there is a way to download the data in the source code's comment.But I haven't used the `GStreamer` , so I have difficult to use the download function with Qt.

And only useful information I found is :[QMediaPlayer API for download the playing stream](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/LFNfvMaPE2IZQHvr2yq1) .But I don't know how to get my way . Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download your media and play after, you can't do it this :

```
pReply = mgr.get(request);
```

Use the "finish" signal of `QNetworkAccessManager`.
void `QNetworkAccessManager::finished ( QNetworkReply * reply )`

Don't forget, when you initializing your `QMediaPlayer`, you should use `QMediaPlayer::StreamPlayback`

```
QMediaPlayer* player = new QMediaPlayer(0, QMediaPlayer::StreamPlayback);
```

And i found this, maybe you have a bug with your Qt version :

[Link](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-32963?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel)

Comment: I want download the buffered music not play it after download.So the finished signal may be not I find.And the bug isn't effect my version -- 5.2. It plays perfect if I just pass the url to it . And the `QMediaPlayer::StreamPlayback` flag will be useful. I will try it.